# Closing the app in samsung smart tv

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I am a beginner to the samsung smart tv app development. I want to close my app on click of exit button. I used the code like this

```
case tvKey.KEY_EXIT:
    var widgetAPI = new Common.API.Widget(); 
    widgetAPI.sendExitEvent();
    break;
```

It is not closing my app. Can anyone help me to fix this issue

Comment: did you test it on real device or just emulator? The emulator not so real with RETURN and EXIT

Comment: I tested with the emulator. can you tell me whether the code i used is correct or not.

Comment: If you're launching emulator from SDK then the apps won't closed. Try to open emulator as stand-alone and load the apps from Emulator's Smart Hub. If the emulator doesn't have smart hub so the apps cannot be closed. PS: I don't think anything wrong in your code

Comment: ok thanks. i will try this. post ur comment as answer

Answer (score 0):

Please Check whether u have following links in the header of your page

```
<!-- Common widget API -->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Widget.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/TVKeyValue.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Plugin.js"></script>
```

One more thing, if you want to simply exit on the press of exit button then you dont have to code any thing as by default pressing exit button will exit the app on the tv, but you can override this functionality by blocking the default exit functionality